# Some emails from my Postfix server return

Tags: email, postfix, email-server

I run a little greeting cards web-site on VPS. It uses Postfix to send greeting cards to clients. Currently the volume is tiny, about 10-20 cards per day. There is absolutely no spam activity (at least to my knowledge) and my IP is **not** blacklisted in such organizations as [MAPS](http://www.mail-abuse.org), [www.abuse.net](http://www.abuse.net), etc.

I noticed that there are cases when the emails are not delivered. There are 3 major types of faults:

**1. User mailbox rejections**

Messages:

- 550 Message was not accepted -- invalid mailbox
- Recipient address rejected: User unknown in relay recipient table (in reply to RCPT TO command)
- The e-mail address you entered couldn't be found. Please check the recipient's e-mail
  address and try to resend the message. If the problem continues, please contact your
  helpdesk.
- 550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try 550-5.1.1 double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or 550-5.1.1 unnecessary spaces. Learn more at 550 5.1.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=6596
  bk8si48484441wjb.30 (in reply to RCPT TO command)
- etc

I get this for different mail servers including gmail, yahoo, mail.ru, etc. I admit that some users may make a typo but it appears that the rate is way too high, I cannot believe there so many typos can be made.

**2. Greylisting**

One server reports this:

host mxs.ukr.net[195.214.192.100] said: 451
    http://ukr.net/mta/std3.html?my_ip (in reply to RCPT TO command)

The link goes to the page on that server where they suggest "to properly setup queue runners".

**3. Unauthorised requests**

host mx9.i.ua[82.144.223.46] said: 451 Unauthorised request. Try again later (in reply to RCPT TO command)

**Here are my questions, applicable to my case:**

1. How difficult would be to fix these issues?
2. Would you recommend to hire a professional IT-specialist to configure email server?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: if the rate of mistyped adresses to freemailers is unusually high I'd check your logs if spambots are trying to abuse your form. make sure you have captchas or similar anti-bot measures in place.

Comment: The thing is that I have 10 cards per day on average so I am not sure if spambot would do such tiny sending. Do you think it is possible?

Comment: Unless you have real users complaining that their cards are not being delivered, the generic answer to questions like this is, "Welcome to the Internet".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really "fix" a user who mistypes an email address. So there's not much you can do about those bounces.

As for the two greylisting examples you gave, just wait them out; postfix will resend the messages.

Comment: Could the "mailbox not found" type messages be related to my side?

Comment: Only if _you_ screwed up the email address, and not the user.

Comment: The link from ukr.net states "there is no way to pass filters without properly configured queue runners" - are you sure there is no problem with greylisting?

Comment: Also, what about #3, an Unauthorised request?

Comment: Right. Postfix will resend the message automatically, if it's running. Its queue runner is named `qmgr` and should be one of the processes running on your server.

Comment: The "Unauthorised request" is just another greylisting.

Comment: So essentially, do you mean that the aforementioned problems are quite a normal situation (to a certain extent)?

Comment: Yes, essentially, what you experience is normal and there isn't much you can or need to do about it.

Comment: Both answers are not ideal but both did provided some useful info for me. I feel I have to award Michael as he was the first one to reply. Nevertheless, many thanks to Kazimieras Aliulis, daff and the others.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** There may be mistyped addresses or your software writes them incorrect but it is unlikely a server problem.

**2. and 3.** Errors starting with 4** is not permanent and mail server should store such emails in queue and deliver later. This feature is exploited by graylisting, because most spammers send e-mails using scripts and do not implement queue. So it is a normal behavior, that mostly do not require fixing. First check, if those emails do not get delivered later.

**More on 3.** Error number is a real error reason. Text after it can sometimes be misleading. Better check, what specification says about error number.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to check if those emails had been eventually delivered?

Comment: Check your mail queue with the `mailq` command to see which messages are still held and review the Postfix log files (probably `/var/log/mail.log`) once the queue is empty. The logs will tell you if the messages were delivered properly or, if not, what happened to them.